# Best/Easier way to add a shape/image to a Dynamics AX 2009 form?

Tags: image, axapta, shapes, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I would like to add a few coloured square shapes to a form in order to display a legend. Since I haven't come across any way of adding coloured-in shapes, I've resorted to creating the shapes as images, loading them as resources and am currently trying to load them to the form...although this seems like a lengthy workaround for a simple single-coloured square.

First off, is there any way of adding a basic shape of a given colour to an AX form? Otherwise, is there any easier way of adding the image to the form without having to replicate the CompanyImage (or CompanyInfo) form?

NOTE: I'm looking to have the image stored within AX proper and not having the image linked by a filepath to an image on the local machine.

Comment: It depends on the shape you want to add, but for simple ones you can use [WinGdi class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa869106%28v=ax.50%29.aspx). You can look at the tetris tutorial in the forms for an example.

Comment: Gave the WinGDI class a shot but for some reason the rectangles weren't showing up. I tried locking and unlocking the window control I was adding to (as per the tetris example) but to no avail.

In the end I resorted to creating picture boxes and set their background colour and size appropriately.

Unfortunately, other than the tetris tutorial, there doesn't seem to be too many WinGDI "tutorials" for Axapta out there. Thanks all the same @Pierre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw simple shapes with the [`WinGDI Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg785039.aspx).
Here is a simple sample :

```
void drawShapes()
{
    WinGDI winGDI;
    Int brush, height, width;
    ;

    //myWindow being the FormWindowControl
    height = myWindow.heightValue()/2;
    width  = myWindow.widthValue()/2;

    myWindow.lockDC();

    winGDI  = new WinGDI(myWindow.hDC());

    brush = winGdi.createSolidBrush(WinAPI::RGB2int(0, 0, 255));
    winGDI.fillRect(0, 0, width, height, brush);
    winGDI.deleteObject(brush);

    winGDI.ellipse(0, 0, width, height);

    brush = winGdi.createSolidBrush(WinAPI::RGB2int(255, 0, 0));
    winGDI.fillRect(width, height, 2*width, 2*height, brush);
    winGDI.deleteObject(brush);

    myWindow.UnlockDC();
}
```

I assume you got something similar.

Now if you just call it once in the form's `init`, the drawing's will be erased as soon as the `paint` method of the window control is called (and it's called pretty often).

So the easiest way is to call it in the `paint` method of the window. This way every time myWindow's content is redrawn, your shapes are too.
You can also force the redrawing of the shapes at a (short) regular time interval like the Tetris Tutorial does *(look at the `cycle` method)* using `setTimeout` but it may be overkill for static content.

You should now have this

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

You can store images as containers (BLOB) on the database and show them on a form or a report:

[How to: Add an Image to a Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa890890%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a simple workaround but this what i did for one of my changes. Since you wanted to use it for legend you can just add a button and set the property as flat, give it a color and a text. That should be good enough as a legend.